# Could not find implicit value in Scala 2.10.1 but in 2.9.3

Tags: scala

Why is the compiler not able to find the implicit value `TypeClass[Boolean]` when using scala 2.10.1? Scala 2.9.3 has no problem with that!

```
package object mypackage extends Feature
package mypackage {
  trait Feature {
    trait TypeClass[T]
    implicit object TCB extends TypeClass[Boolean] {}
  }
  object Main extends App {
    val itcb = implicitly[TypeClass[Boolean]] // could not find implicit value for parameter e: mypackage.TypeClass[Boolean]
  }
}
```

Comment: As for me, Scala 2.10.1 is right, there isn't even any instance of `Feature` from which your implicit object could be fetched. Are you sure that Scala 2.9.3 is fine with that?

Comment: @ghik What about the package object then? It does extend `Feature`.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet Oh you're right. Sorry, I missed it.

Comment: Another reason why I think this shouldn't compile: if implicit parameter isn't directly visible, then it is looked up in so called _implicit scope_ of parameter's type. Implicit scope is made of companion objects of classes _associated_ with parameter's type (SLS 7.2). I don't see any companion objects in above code.

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug (or at least an omission in package object spec). I tried several variations. It seems that implicit definitions brought into scope by package object inheritance are overlooked during implicit resolution from within the package.

Comment: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4695 seems relevant to this, even if the particular bug is about recompilation detection. In general, it seems like the Scala compiler doesn't like a package object extending from something that lives within it, and Odersky appears to want to kill that functionality altogether due to the complications. Perhaps we should add this issue to the list of things that go wrong in that pattern?